# How to access variables from different screens in python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

As title states, I would like to figure out how I would retrieve an object property from 1 screen to another. I have one screen that has an object property but I cant seem to find a way to access that object property in a different screen/class.
For example:

```
class windowOne(Screen):
    myVar = ObjectProperty("Hello")
    pass
class windowTwo(Screen):
    pass
```

I would like to access myVar in windowTwo.
Any ideas? I have my full code if you would like me to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access a variable of `windowOne`, you first need a reference to the instance of `windowOne` that is in your `App`. Typically, you get that reference from the `ScreenManager`.

If you are accessing it from a method of another `Screen`, you can get a reference to the `ScreenManager`like this:

```
screen_manager = self.manager
```

If you are not in a method of another `Screen`, you can often get the reference to the `ScreenManager` as:

```
screen_manager = App.get_running_app().root
```

The above assumes that the `ScreenManager` is the root widget of the `App`.

Once you have the `ScreenManager`, you can use the `get_screen()` method to get a reference to `windowOne`:

```
window_one = screen_manager.get_screen('Name of WindowOne Screen')
```

where `Name of WindowOne Screen` is the name that you assign to the `WindowOne` `Screen`.

And, finally, the `myVar` variable is accessed by:

```
window_one.myVar
```